# Get SOAP response from soap object in webservices

Tags: java, soap

I have the soap address location in my wsdl is as `"<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/rpc/soap/helloworldsoap"/>"`

In my web service method I have the following path.

```
@HttpResource(location="/{name}")
```

I want to get the SOAP response object.

I tried the following url.

**http://localhost:8080/rpc/soap/helloworldsoap/abcd**

**WSDL**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<wsdl:definitions name="HelloWorldImplService" targetNamespace="some name space" xmlns:ns1="http://test.com/webservices" xmlns:ns2="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="some name space" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:import location="http://localhost:8080/rpc/soap/helloworldsoap?wsdl=HelloWorld.wsdl" namespace="http://test.com/webservices">
    </wsdl:import>
  <wsdl:binding name="HelloWorldImplServiceSoapBinding" type="ns1:HelloWorld">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="getHelloWorldAsString">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="rpc" />
      <wsdl:input name="getHelloWorldAsString">
        <soap:body namespace="http://test.com/webservices" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getHelloWorldAsStringResponse">
        <soap:body namespace="http://test.com/webservices" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="HelloWorldImplService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:HelloWorldImplServiceSoapBinding" name="HelloWorldImplPort">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/rpc/soap/helloworldsoap" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

SOAP:

```
    <soap:Envelope>
       <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
       <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>No such operation:  (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /soap/helloworldsoap)     
      </faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

But I am not getting the response object.

Can any one tell me how to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in confusion whether we can use the Resource location for SOAP. For REST, it holds good,
and also from your error, it gives error on server side(your input holds good)that too about location.

Try some thing like this...

**Remove Resource location, use @WebMethod.**

Post your Interface definition and also SOAP input.

Example :

Interface:

```
@WebService
public interface Service {

public Address validate(Address address);

@WebMethod
public String sayHi(
    @WebParam(mode = WebParam.Mode.IN)
    String msg);
}
```

Implementation:

```
package com.example;
```

import javax.jws.WebService;

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.example.AddressService" )
public class AddressServiceImpl implements AddressService {

@Override
public Address validateAdress(Address address) {
     return  address;
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHi(String msg) {
        return "Vinay";
    }
}
```

Hope the example helps

Answer (score 0):

You  have  not  given much information. But try

telnet  to localhost  8080, to see  if  service  is  running

If  it  is  then use  curl from the  commandline to check that the WSDL is  actually  available.

Comment: @Dave.. Thanks for the response. That service is running. Adding wsdl and other files. Please have alook